# How to draw triangle with rounded corner

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create a triangle with rounded corners like this. How can I implement this?

I've tried searching for related answers, but only found implementations without rounded corners.

Is there any way to implement a similar triangle without using static images?

[image]

Comment: try [quadraticBezierTo](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/quadraticBezierTo.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `CustomPainter`. Following is the code for this:

```dart
class RoundedTrianglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double width = size.width;
    final double height = size.height;
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blueGrey
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo((width / 2) - 16, 80)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset((width / 2) + 16, 80),
        radius: Radius.circular(22),
        clockwise: true,
      )
      ..lineTo(width, height)
      ..lineTo(0, height)
      ..close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```dart
Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  child: CustomPaint(
    painter: RoundedTrianglePainter(),
  ),
),
```

**Output:**

[image: Triangle with rounded corner]

Answer (score 0):

You can draw on a canvas and use different strokeJoin values.  See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paint/strokeJoin.html

Here's an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Triangle',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: TrianglePainter(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TrianglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..strokeWidth = 10
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round;


    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(10, 10);
    path.lineTo(50, 50);
    path.lineTo(10, 50);
    path.lineTo(10, 10);
    path.lineTo(50, 50);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is more adaptive and gives the right rotation like the image,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Triangle',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: Center(
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: TrianglePainter(Colors.blue),
            size: Size(200, 200),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TrianglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color color;

  TrianglePainter(this.color);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo((size.width / 2) - 16, 120)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset((size.width / 2) + 16, 120),
        radius: const Radius.circular(21),
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For more generic triangle, im using this code.

```
 Path getTriangle(Size size, double radius) {
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0.0 + radius, size.height - radius * 1.4);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(0.0 + (radius * 2), size.height),
        radius: Radius.circular(radius), clockwise: false);
    path.lineTo(size.width - radius * 2, size.height);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width - radius, size.height - radius * 1.4),
        radius: Radius.circular(radius), clockwise: false);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2 + radius, 0.0 + radius * 2);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width / 2 - radius, 0.0 + radius * 2),
        radius: Radius.circular(radius * 1.1), clockwise: false);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }
```

[image: Triangle made by code above]

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely yes!
This solution is more generic and allows you to specify the corner radius. Instead of just giving the solution i think its best to show you how i reached the solution using this image
[mathematical solution of drawing a triangle with a rounded corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQT1s.png)

You can use basic trigonometric functions to get all the much needed sides.
Having pondered about that its time to write the code.

1.create a new project

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'dart:math' as math;

 void main() {
   runApp(const MyApp());
 }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

 // This widget is the root of your application.
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Rounded Triangle',
  
         home: MyHomePage(),
         debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     );
   }
 }

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  const MyHomePage();
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(//container whose height and width are used
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            child: CustomPaint(//dispays the round corner triangle
            painter: MyRoundTriangle(radius: 45),
            ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
  }

}
```

2.next create the MyRoundTriangle  custom painter class right below the above code

```
class MyRoundTriangle extends CustomPainter{
  const MyRoundTriangle({required this.radius,Key? key});
final double radius;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final H = size.height;//height of container
    final B = size.width;//width of container
    final angleAlpha = math.atan(2*H/B);//calculating angleAlpha
    final angleBeta = math.pi /2 -angleAlpha;//calculating angleBeta
    final S = radius/math.cos(angleAlpha);//distance fromTopCenter to 
    //center of arc
    final L = radius * math.tan(angleAlpha);//hypoteneus of smaller 
    //triangle
    final h = L * math.sin(angleAlpha);//height of smaller triangle
    final b = 2*L*math.cos(angleAlpha);//base length of smaller triangle

    final paint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.grey
    ..strokeWidth = 1
    ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    //path for drawing the trapezium without the arc

    final basePath = Path()
    ..moveTo(size.width/2,size.height)
    ..relativeLineTo(-size.width/2,0)
    ..relativeLineTo(B-(B/2 + b/2),-H+h)
    ..relativeLineTo(b,0)
    ..lineTo(B,H)
    ..close;

    //square for drawing the arc inside

    final arcRect = Rect.fromCenter(
     center:Offset(B/2,S),
      width:2* radius,
      height:2* radius,
    );

    //path for drawing the arc

    final arcPath = Path()
    ..addArc(arcRect,math.pi + angleBeta,2*angleAlpha)
    ..close;

    //combining the two paths to have a round corner triangle

    final completePath = 
     Path.combine(PathOperation.union,basePath,arcPath);

     //drawing the triangle on the screen

     canvas.drawPath(completePath,paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
   return false;
  }

}
```

To test the code in action heres a link https://zapp.run/edit/rounded-triangle-zm1606axm170?file=lib/main.dart

The output of the code above should be a grey triangle with a rounded corner at the top as shown below
[grey triangle with a round corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gms0i.png)